# getting cloud_firestore: 0.9.0 dependency breaks flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, package

I've added the [cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-installing-tab-) package to my new flutter project, so I created a new flutter project just for testing the Firebase package.

and got this error, after "package get", and starting the project.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > project :cloud_firestore
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.19.110] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
            > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/52.28.74.46, jcenter.bintray.com/52.28.100.213] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.19.110] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/17.1.0/firebase-firestore-17.1.0.pom'.
            > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/52.28.100.213, jcenter.bintray.com/52.28.74.46] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 7s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Steps to recreate:

1. Copy the firebase package version for pubspec.yaml cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0 and add this to the pubspect.yamel file. and do package get.
2. Downloaded google-services.json after creating an account on the firebase website.
3. FLUTTERAPP/android/buld.grundle ive added this line of code

   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
4. FLUTTERAPP/android/app/build.grundle at the end i've added this like of code

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

started the app..

I'm using android studio with an Android emulator, on windows 10

MY_APP/android/buld.randle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

MY_APP/android/app/build.grundle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.newapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please provide your FLUTTERAPP/android/buld.gradle (Project level) and FLUTTERAPP/android/app/build.grade (App level) file contents

Comment: here you go, I've added it to the edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem [RE: Flutter how to fix The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.] can be fixed by changing the app/build.gradle minSdkVersion value from 16 to 21. I think this is the same problem as above﻿ (or related) as I was having, but with a different error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should also add the dependencies for the Firebase SDKs you want to use.

Add         `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`
 to your MY_APP/android/app/build.grandle files a dependancy section like below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\src\FlutterApps\firebase\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar,

Comment: Try to open and build your android specific folder on Android studio, Then you will get some more meaningful error message